# subprocess.call on long standing process

Tags: python

I'm using subprocess.call to run an external ffmpeg process that usually takes 1hr approx. What I see is that apparently after some time (for example 20min) my program is closed without returning from subprocess.call.

Example:

```
import subprocess
try:
  ret = subprocess.call(['ffmpeg', 'param1', 'param2', 'paramN'])
  print(ret)
except:
  print("An exception has occured!")
```

The `print` line is never reached.

Comment: Try Popen its better option then subprocess for heavy OS processes.  I had similar problem while running OS command using subprocess the issue was with the memory, OS can't alloacate memory for OS command, so OS just return with out any status.   https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module

Comment: Don't use a blank except, does your code  print the exception message or just hangs forever?

Comment: I'll try with Popen. @PadraicCunningham it doesn't hang, it crashes the caller program without any hint.

Comment: what args are you passing?

Answer (score 0):

You might be running out of memory.  Linux starts killing processes when the system is about to overflow. And it can kill the parent process rather than the offending `ffmpeg` process. Check your `dmesg` and syslog records.